# Using document.getElementsByTagName, how can I modify this object on click?

Tags: jquery

I have an h1 element (one of several on the page) that I would like to change when I click it.  I have convinced myself that document.getElementsByTagName is working to select particular "h1" elements.  Unfortunately I expected the code below to make an action on click but it is having no effect:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[1].click(function() {

this.style.fontSize = "9vw";
  
});
```

[image]

Comment: `$this` should be just `this`

Comment: thanks - I made this edit and it is still not working, but let me update the post!

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: Are you sure `[1]` is the correct index? Depending on indexes like that is generally a bad idea. Give the element an ID and use that.

Comment: I tested this by adding 3 h1 elements.  The code is working as expected affecting only element [1] - you're right though, in the future I might want to use an element ID instead of index to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issue that I found in the code are listed below.

- Your selector is tagged as `document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[1]`. Are you sure to select the second `h1` node? If yes, this is not an issue. Or else make sure that this is valid. I have used `document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0]` because, I'm pointing to the first `h1` element in the page
- `click` function invocation is wrong. In this statement `document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[1].click(function() { this.style.fontSize = "9vw"; });` what you are doing is passing a function as an argument to the click function. `document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[1].click()` this invokes the click of the selected node. If you want to assing a function as the click event listner, you have to do it as

  ```
   document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].onclick = function () {
     console.log('You clicked me');
   };
  ```
- Or you can add an eventlistner for the click event using

  ```
   document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
     console.log('You clicked me')
   });
  ```

**Working Fiddle**

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].onclick = function () {
  console.log('You clicked me');
  this.style.fontSize = "9vw";
};
```

```html
<h1>Click to update me</h1>
```

Comment: You might as well show how to use `addEventListener()` instead of `onclick`

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to call the jQuery method `.click()` on a DOM element. Use a jQuery selector and `.eq()` to select a specific item by index, then you can use `.click()`.

```
$("h1").eq(1).click(function() {
    $(this).css("font-size", "9vw");
});
```